# How to compute cellular homology of a handle decomposition $D^m\cup H^{\gamma_1}\cup\dots\cup H^{\gamma_N}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

Let $X_k=X_{k-1}\cup_{\chi} H^{\gamma_k}$ be a $\dim X_{k-1}$-manifold with a $\gamma_k$-handle $H^{\gamma_k}=D^{\dim X_{k-1}-\gamma_k}\times D^{\gamma_k}$ attached along the embedding map $\chi:S^{\gamma_k-1}\times D^{\dim X_{k-1}-\gamma_k}\to\partial X_{k-1}$ with $X_0:=D^m$ (an $m$-ball), $X:=X_N$ for $1\le k\le N$.

> Then, how do we compute the $n$-th homology group of $X$ for all $n\ge 0$ (via cellular homology for CW complexes) in $\mathbb{Q}$-coefficients, i.e. $H_n(X;\mathbb{Q})=H_n(D^m\cup_{\chi} H^{\gamma_1}\cup_{\chi}\dots\cup_{\chi} H^{\gamma_N};\mathbb{Q})$? In short, how do we compute homology of a handle decomposition?

There is a deformation retraction of $M\cup H^k$ onto the core $M\cup_{S^{k−1}}(D^k\times 0)$, so homotopically attaching a $k$-handle is the same as attaching a $k$-cell. Thus, we may use cellular homology of the CW complex $X'$ given by collapsing each handle $D^k\times D^{n−k}$ to $D^k$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: A handle decomposition is similar to a cell decomposition. In both cases you can set up a chain complex to compute the homology.

Comment: So, do you mean via cellular homology in this instance? @CheerfulParsnip

Comment: It's not exactly cellular homology, it just behaves exactly the same way. The $k$-handles are just thickened $k$-cells and you need to examine the degrees of the attaching maps.

Comment: If you have a handle decomposition you can collapse each handle $D^k \times D^{n-k}$ to $D^k$ to get a homotopy equivalent CW complex $X'$ with the same number of k-cells as your manifold has k-handles. Then our vegetable friend's chain complex is the same as the cellular chain complex of $X'$.

Comment: I strongly suggest trying this computation explicitly for a handle structure on $\Sigma_g$ with only one 0- and 2-handle.

Comment: @Multivariablecalculus There has been 30 edits in this question (up to now). Please, try to refrain from overediting posts.

Comment: @MikeMiller I am familiar with the computation (of Hatcher, AT) $$H_n({\Sigma}_g)=\begin{cases} 
      \mathbb{Z}, & n=0,2 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise.}  
   \end{cases}$$ So does a similar argument for this case yield $$H_k(X)=H_k^{CW}(X)=\begin{cases} 
        0,       & \text{if }k\ne\gamma_1,\dots,\gamma_N \\
      \mathbb{Z}^{n_{\gamma_1}}, & \text{if }k=\gamma_1 \\
      &\vdots\\
      \mathbb{Z}^{n_{\gamma_N}}, & \text{if }k=\gamma_N \\
      \mathbb{Z}_2, & \text{if }k=0   
   \end{cases}$$?